# Where does ethminer mining reward go ? No option to provide wallet address

Tags: cpp-ethereum, claymore, reward

I did a count on [this forum](https://www.reddit.com/r/EtherMining/), and seems like most people there mine with [ethminer](https://github.com/ethereum-mining/ethminer#usage). I've always been using claymore miner which has the `-ewal` option to provide my ether address, but there's no equivalent option in ethminer program. So where does my mining reward go to ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ethminer` has the `--farm` [option](https://gist.github.com/jmiehau/0470ef3262d83987221e) which allows you to set where your miner fetches work from. If you're solo mining (the default option works for that), then you configure the address from your Ethereum client (`geth`, `parity`, etc.). If it's a pool, you use the settings provided by the pool so that it knows where to send payment for work.